# React-Native JSON and PHP API not working, wors with Postman

Tags: php, json, react-native, post, fetch

I have a fairly simple react-native feature that updates a remote database via a rest api using post. The problem is that while I can get the PHP to respond correctly using Postman, the server doesn't work with react. Anyone have thoughts?

**PHP Code**

```
<?

header('Access-Control-Max-Age: 3628800');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST');
header('Content-Type: application/json');

if($_POST["clothing_uid"]){
    $clothing_uid = $_POST["clothing_uid"];
}else{
    $clothing_uid = 'No clothing id specified';
}
$comments = $_POST["comments"];

$response = array(
    "status" => 200,
    "clothing_uid" => $clothing_uid,
    "comments" => $comments,
    );
echo json_encode($response);
?>
```

**React-Native Code**

```
async function updateClothes (clothing_uid, comments){
    const updateObject = {
        "clothing_uid" : clothing_uid,
        "comments" : {comments}
    }

    const requestOptions = {
        method: 'POST',
        mode: 'cors',
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
        body: JSON.stringify(updateObject)
    };
    
    
    const url = apiUrl + 'clothes/update.php';
    try{
        const response = await fetch(url, requestOptions);
        const data = await response.json();
        console.log(data);
        return data;
    }catch (error){
        console.log(error);
    }
}
module.exports.updateClothes = updateClothes;
```

**Postman Output**
[image]

**React-Native Console Log**

```
 LOG  {"body": "{\"clothing_uid\":\"123123\",\"comments\":{\"comments\":\"This is a test comment\"}}", "headers": {"Content-Type": "application/json"}, "method": "POST", "mode": "cors"}
 LOG  {"clothing_uid": "No clothing id specified", "comments": null, "status": 200}
```

Any thoughts on where I am going wrong? not sure if its the extra 's being added by JSON.stringify but I haven't had any success even when I've tried without JSON.stringify

Comment: The request you are sending in postman is not actually `Content-Type: application/json` ...

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out using postman. Solution is to use FormData instead.

```
async function updateClothes (clothing_uid, comments){

var formdata = new FormData();
    formdata.append("clothing_uid", clothing_uid);
    formdata.append("comments", comments);
    var requestOptions = {
        method: 'POST',
        body: formdata,
        redirect: 'follow'
      };

const url = apiUrl + 'clothes/update.php';
    try{
        const response = await fetch(url, requestOptions);
        const data = await response.json();
        return data;
    }catch (error){
        console.log(error);
    }
}
```